# Dell Ubuntu 18.04 freezes on startup

Tags: dell, freeze

I have a new laptop `Inspiron 3583`, I got it with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

The first time I ran it, it worked fine. I configured my username etc. After system update, I restarted the computer. After the BIOS screen, the system freezes with a blank purple screen, without showing any error or message. I just have that blank purple screen and I haven't got a choice to enter some password. It freezes before that.

I did a restore to factory state and it got back to work. But after some restarts without updates, the problem happened again.

What can be the cause of this problem?